# Masstransit Request/Response vs Restful webservice

Tags: rest, web-services, masstransit

In a microservice oriented architecture, what are the usecases for masstransit vs restful webservices to communicate between microservices.

Of course masstransit (MQ) has it's huge advantages when using asynchronus communication. But when there are synchronous requests, what are the advantages of masstransit vs restful services?

I know it is a bit broad.

Answer (score 5):

Advantages are:

- Less spatial coupling - you send messages to the message broker without knowing where the receiver is located
- Easier load balancing - you don't need any additional infrastructure except the message broker to run competing consumers, pull model is more honest than the push model
- Built-in retries for transient failures like database locks (things like Polly can help here too with HTTP of course)
- Keep failures in the poison message queue for further analysis

This is something that comes to my mind immediately.

Performance-wise the overhead of using messages is marginal but of course, for larger volumes it can have significant negative impact.

In general, synchronous communication between services, no matter what transport is, is something to be avoided since it kills the idea of microservice autonomy.